# Python Авторизация Steam

Tags: python, steam

Здравствуйте.
Подскажите,как организовать авторизацию в Steam? Много перерыл,исходников рабочих не нашел. Так же хотелось бы,чтобы сессия не закрывалась при парсинге новой страницы,чтобы не приходилось заново авторизовываться.
Пытался сам написать,все тщетно,последний раз работал с вебом на питоне 5 лет назад и то под Symbian. Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Comment: а про steam web api слышал?

Comment: Слышал,я собираюсь парсить цены предметов из игр,а это API мне вряд ли поможет,просто беда в том,что мне цены нужны в рублях,а при парсинге без логина,они в доллорах.

Comment: Ахахах. Вот это проблема :D А взять свежий курс и перевести в рубли - слишком сложно?

Comment: Беда в том что,цены по стим различаются в регионах. Т.е. в России в рублях купить игру получается дешевле,чем в долларах.

Comment: А-а. Если я правильно понял, то это проблема, да. Решения не знаю, просто интересно.